# best way I put many images in one column or create another table for the images with a relationship

Tags: mysql, database, normalization

I make a table for products and the product contains many of image.best way I put the images in one column or create another table for the images with a relationship.

Comment: add column product.image and add url no?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini not if there are multiple images (as stated in the question), no. It would need to be a second table with a foreign key back to the main products table.

Comment: @ADyson 'if' yes, but we don't know :), but is right your reasoning

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I'd say the question wording "product contains many of image" makes it pretty clear, to be honest.